# How to import an image in MainActivity

Tags: image, android-activity, import

this is Dev. I want to know that how to insert or import an image into main activity. When I press on image View and press alt + enter It dose not show me import option. So, how I import this.

Answer (score 0):

try doing a left click upon the ImageView, and then you will see a light bulb on the left side of the view, click on that you will find the option to import ImageView.

let me know if this works.